# How to make a function that returns a function?

Tags: functions

I have this function that returns another function Hs but the only way to use the function is to use Hs[t][[1]]. Is this going to slow down my code and is there a way to write this so that I can access Hs[t] in the normal way?

```
getHs[maxh_ : 2] :=
 Function[{t}, Module[{Hs, k, n},
   Hs = 0; 
   For[k = 1, k < maxh + 2, k++, 
    For[n = 0, n < Ceiling[(maxh - k + 2)/2], n++,
     Hs += (Sy (I h)^(2 n + k))/(h (n + k)! n!)
        f[k, t] pow[ad, n + k] ** pow[a, n]; 
     Hs += (Sy (-I h)^(2 n + k))/(h (n + k)! n!)
        f[k, t]\[Conjugate] pow[ad, n] ** pow[a, n + k];
     ]]; Return[Hs]]]

Hs := getHs[3]
Hs[t][[1]]

-I a Sy Conjugate[f[1, t]] + I ad Sy f[1, t] - 
 1/2 h Sy Conjugate[f[2, t]] a ** a - 1/2 h Sy f[2, t] ad ** ad + 
 1/6 I h^2 Sy Conjugate[f[3, t]] a ** a ** a + 
 1/2 I h^2 Sy Conjugate[f[1, t]] ad ** a ** a - 
 1/2 I h^2 Sy f[1, t] ad ** ad ** a - 
 1/6 I h^2 Sy f[3, t] ad ** ad ** ad + 
 1/24 h^3 Sy Conjugate[f[4, t]] a ** a ** a ** a + 
 1/6 h^3 Sy Conjugate[f[2, t]] ad ** a ** a ** a + 
 1/6 h^3 Sy f[2, t] ad ** ad ** ad ** a + 
 1/24 h^3 Sy f[4, t] ad ** ad ** ad ** ad
```

Comment: Use "Set" and not "SetDelayed":  Hs = getHs[3]

Comment: I guess you can use `Sum`.